# Smart Card errors

Tags: windows-7, smartcard

I have a [CAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Access_Card) smart card, and a [SCM Microsystems SCR3310 USB card Reader](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001L6OVZM).  I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate with SP1.

This setup used to work just fine. When I would insert my CAC, my certificates would immediately propagate to the certificate store (as evidenced by Certificate Manager, `certmgr.msc`), and I could log on to websites that required a CAC for access.

Recently, I stopped being able to access the websites. Looking in Certificate Manager, I see that only one, or sometimes two of my certificates are present. If I delete them, and re-insert my card a different certificate may appear.

I just returned and replaced the reader with the same model, so I know it is not the culprit.

I finally thought to look at the system log, and noticed the following errors upon smart card insertion:

[image]

---

The errors, in chronological order:

```
Smart Card Service    Event ID: 610
   Smart Card Reader 'SCM Microsystems SCR33xx v2.0 USB SC Reader 0' rejected
   IOCTL TRANSMIT: Incorrect function.  If this error persists, your smart card
   or reader may not be functioning correctly.

   Command Header: 00 c0 00 00

WudfUsbccidDrv        Event ID: 11
   A Request has returned failure.
   MsgType: 0x80
   ICCStatus: 0x0
   CmdStatus: 0x1
   Error: 0xf6               // ICC_PROTOCOL_NOT_SUPPORTED
   SW1: 0x0
   SW2: 0x0

WudfUsbccidDrv        Event ID: 11
   An operation has failed (0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0).
   ScT0Transmit: Failed to send request at TPDU level.
   HResult: The specified request is not a valid operation for the target device.
   // Note: this one comes from WUDFUsbccidDriver.dll CMyDevice::UsbScT0Transmit+7D0h

WudfUsbccidDrv        Event ID: 10
   Request[0](CLS=0x0,INS=0xc0,P1=0x0,P2=0x0,Lc=0,Le=256,.NETServiceMethod=0x0)
```

It appears that the hardware indicated failure during the `IOCTL TRANSMIT`, which trickled down through the user-mode driver framework.

**Edit:** Consulting the CCID spec, it appears that the card is responding back with 
`bmCommandStatus = 1 - Failed (error code provided by the error register)`. And `Error = ICC_PROTOCOL_NOT_SUPPORTED -10 (F6h)`.  I'm assuming the driver translates this error into the "HResult: The specified request is not a valid operation for the target device." message.

Also, the command being sent was INS=0xC0, which is [GET RESPONSE](http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_7_transmission_interindustry_commands.aspx).

How can it say protocol not supported? What is the driver doing differently than when it worked?  Note that I also just tried this with a new CAC, and I'm seeing similar behavior. A problem with the card reader, or driver?

---

Considering I just replaced the reader (and re-installed drivers, rebooted, etc.) is there something wrong with my Smart Card? I'm assuming not, because it *does* work with another reader on another system. I haven't tried a different reader on the same system.

In fact, the *same* reader connected to a Windows 7 VM on the same physical machine works just fine! Something is clearly broken, and it's driving me nuts trying to figure out what.

So what is the problem?

Comment: I just had a lovely chat session with a Jasper V from Microsoft, that provided exactly zero insight into the problem: http://pastebin.com/dvU3dNfa

Comment: I have the same problem, do you find a solution?

Comment: I installed Linux.

Comment: Hi @JonathonReinhart, sorry to hijack this post but I have the exact same issue, do you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 4):

Just in case if someone would stuck with that issue - I have been trying to fix it for like a whole day long.

Here's the solution:

1. For 64-bit Windows - jump to the registry key at

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\Readers
   ```

There should be some readers already.
And if not, so that's the reason why you may have all the drivers installed, but still not functioning at all.

2. Go to `Device Manager`, find the reader in question then look out for this string in Details tab: `Bus reported device description`.
3. Create a subkey for the key above. The name should be exactly the same to that `Bus reported device description`. Then add a counter at the end. So the key should be like this one:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\Readers\O2Micro CCID SC Reader 0
   ```
4. Now create a couple string values: first one with Device name and second for groups.
   Here's my example:

   ```
   Device = O2Micro CCID SC Reader 0

   Groups = SCard$DefaultReaders
   ```

That's it. To make it work disconnect the reader and connect it back. In case of internal devices, you may have to reboot the machine.
And here's the `.reg` file example (change device name and number to your own values):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptography\Calais\Readers\O2Micro CCID SC Reader 0]
"Device"="O2Micro CCID SC Reader 0"
"Groups"=hex(7):53,00,43,00,61,00,72,00,64,00,24,00,44,00,65,00,66,00,61,00,75,\
00,6c,00,74,00,52,00,65,00,61,00,64,00,65,00,72,00,73,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: Although your question is very specific, thank you for sharing your insights. +1

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what this is supposed to accomplish. My device is clearly connected, and the driver is communicating with the reader.

Comment: Hello, I already have a reader listed but subkey name & string values are different from bus reported device description. 
Should i just add additional subkey with string or should also remove older one?